# LLVM segmentation fault / need use Instruction instead of Instruction*

Tags: c++, llvm

I have a segmentation fault while running an LLVM pass. I need to use BBterminators array outside the iterating "for" loop for basic blocks. It seems that LLVM does not protect the addresses (note: `TerminatorInst *BasicBlock::getTerminator()`) when iterating through the loop, so I need to keep BBterminators in a variable of type `Instruction`, not `Instruction *`. How can I copy the entire `Instructions` into `BBterminators`?

```
for (Function::iterator II = F.begin(), EE = F.end(); II != EE; ++II, ++ii)
{
BasicBlock* BB = (dyn_cast<BasicBlock>(II));

if (BB->getTerminator())
{
    Instruction *current = BB->getTerminator();

    Instruction *previous = current->getPrevNode();

    if (current->getOpcode() == Instruction::Br) 
    {   
        BBterminators[ii] = current;
```

where `Instruction **BBterminators = new Instruction *[100];`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Introducing a condition

```
if ( !(II->empty()) && II->back().isTerminator() )
```

before of computations

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by "protecting" here. Iterating over BBs and looking at their terminators certainly doesn't invalidate the instruction pointers, so you can keep them as long as you're safe not to remove anything. In any case, you can also copy `Instruction*` objects by calling `clone` (note that `Instruction` is non-copyable with copy ctor and assignment operator by design). Something like this:

```
virtual bool runOnFunction(Function &F) {
  std::vector<Instruction*> terminators;
    for (Function::iterator bb = F.begin(), bb_e = F.end(); bb != bb_e; ++bb) {
      terminators.push_back(bb->getTerminator()->clone());
    }
  ...
  ...
}
```

Don't forget to release your vector of copies once you're done with it.